# Cucumber/Capybara Tests can't tell Jquery Autocomplete Forms Apart

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

My page looks something like this:

```
#reserve_new
= text_field_tag :autocomplete, '', :id => "agency_autocomplete", :class => [:title, :focus, :string, :required], placeholder: "agency name or ID", data: { search_type: "active_agency", selector: "#pre_executed_bond_number_set_agency_id"}
#results

#lookup_existing
= text_field_tag :autocomplete, '', :id => "agency_autocomplete", :class => [:title, :string, :required], placeholder: "agency name or ID", data: {selector: "#lookup_agency_id", results: "#results2"}
#results2
```

And I have a test that looks like this:

```
when /^I look up pre\-executed numbers for that agency$/ do
  within "#lookup_existing" do
    autocomplete_selector = "#{agency.name} (#{agency.id}) :: #{agency.city}, #{agency.state}"
    step "I choose the \"#{autocomplete_selector}\" autocomplete option"
    click_button "Find"
  end
end
```

which calls

```
When /^I choose the "(.*?)" autocomplete option$/ do |text|
  step "the page should not be an error page"
  find('ul.ui-autocomplete').should have_content(text)

  case Capybara.javascript_driver
  when :selenium
    find('.ui-menu-item a', text: /^#{Regexp.escape(text)}/).click
  when :webkit
    page.execute_script %Q{$('.ui-menu-item:contains("#{text}")').first().find('a').trigger('mouseenter').click();}
  end
end
```

When I comment out either the #reserve_new or #lookup_existing the tests pass, because capybara isn't getting confused. However, when I have both on the same page the tests fail.

I've tried things like

```
within("#reserve_new") do
  find('ul.ui-autocomplete').should have_content(text)
end
```

and `find("#reserve_new").find('ul.ui-autocomplete').should have_content(text)`

And all examples result in failure because capybara/cucumber are operating on the wrong autocomplete.

When I try to find the id and do it inside of that it says it can't find the id.

Any ideas on things to try or hacks that might be useful to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

it's not valid html when you define an ID several times!

`:id => "agency_autocomplete"` must only be there once.

i guess that's what causes capybara to fail.

Comment: I agree that is an issue, but if I change it to find #header it still doesn't find that which only appears once.